# When trying to run the make command I get the following error, I am working with M1 Machine for Mac

Tags: bitcoind, mac, installation

```
xxxxxxx@xxxx-MacBook-Pro bitcoin % make -j 1
Making all in src
  CXX      bitcoind-bitcoind.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fstack-clash-protection' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:14:
In file included from ./interfaces/chain.h:8:
./optional.h:10:10: fatal error: 'boost/optional.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [bitcoind-bitcoind.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `boost` dependency may be missing or outdated. The [build instructions for OS X](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md#3-install-required-dependencies) in the Bitcoin repository suggest that `boost` should be installed via homebrew in the third step, “Install Required Dependencies”. If you were missing that step, maybe try following the linked instructions from the top. If you followed every step of the instructions and still got this error, please file a [bug report](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) on the repository.